# How to Connect mysql using vb.net over lan connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to access mysql database which is from another computer. I had tried to search but couldn't find a solution that answers my question. Hope you can help me.

Here is the error:

> Cannot connect to database: Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'root'
>   using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Unknown database.

And here is the code.

```
    Private Sub CheckCon()
    mySqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
    mySqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1; port=3306; user id=root; password=thesis; database=dbjcasim;"
    Try

        mySqlConn.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Connection to Database has been opened.")
        mySqlConn.Close()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        mySqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct IP? 127.n is usually your own workstation.

Comment: Yes it is the IP of the localhost of the other computer which the database can be found.

Comment: Ok, turn off the other computer. Ping 127.0.0.1. See if you get a response. Usually 127.0.0.1 refers to the localhost and shouldn't be used to connect across a network. You'd need the other computer's Name/IP as far as it appears on the network.

Comment: What is IP of your computer's localhost?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 that's the ip of local host of mySql database in the other computer , i want to access the database to the other computer 
is that possible ?  . thanks in advance .

Comment: Go to the other computer, open a command prompt, type `ipconfig /all` and paste the result here.

Comment: @markanthonymunzon localhost is always the machine you are on. if you try to acces localhost or 127.0.0.1 you will access the machine you are working on. trying to access localhost/127.0.01 you have no chance to access a remote machine: that's the address for the local machine (hence LOCALhost, btw...).